# OOP design: difference between two possible solutions

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, class-design

Say I have a `Car`, that owns a `SpeedBooster` that whenever is `active` and the car has to move, it will add an extra - configurable - speed to that moving action.

I was thinking about how to design-implement this using OOP, and I ended up doubting between two different solutions:

#### Solution 1

The Car is the one that checks if the Booster is `ON` and itself calculates that extra distance that will be added to the final move.

**SpeedBooster Class**

```
class SpeedBooster {

  private active: boolean;
  private speedIncrement: number;

  constructor(speedIncrement: number, active = false) {
    this.active = active;
    this.speedIncrement = speedIncrement;
  }

  public activate(): void {
    this.active = true;
  }

  public deactivate(): void {
    this.active = false;
  }

  public isActive(): boolean {
    return this.active;
  }

  public getSpeedIncrement(): number {
    return this.speedIncrement;
  }

}
```

**Car Class**

```
class Car {

  private position: number;
  private speedBooster: SpeedBooster;

  constructor(speedBooster: SpeedBooster) {
    this.position = 0;
    this.speedBooster = speedBooster;
  }

  public move(distance: number): void {
    if (this.speedBooster.isActive()) {
      let extraDistance = this.speedBooster.getSpeedIncrement() * distance;
      let totalDistance = extraDistance + distance;

      this.position =+ totalDistance;
    } else {
      this.position =+ distance;
    }
  }

  // etc...

}
```

#### Solution 2

The Car just asks the Booster about that extra distance it will have to add to the final move. The Booster knows it's state (`ON`/`OFF`) and returns the extra distance or 0.

**SpeedBooster Class**

```
class SpeedBooster {

  private active: boolean;
  private speedIncrement: number;

  constructor(speedIncrement: number, active = false) {
    this.active = active;
    this.speedIncrement = speedIncrement;
  }

  public activate(): void {
    this.active = true;
  }

  public deactivate(): void {
    this.active = false;
  }

  public calculateExtraDistance(distance) {
    if (this.active) {
      return this.speedIncrement * distance;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

}
```

**Car Class**

```
class Car {

  private position: number;
  private speedBooster: SpeedBooster;

  constructor(speedBooster: SpeedBooster) {
    this.position = 0;
    this.speedBooster = speedBooster;
  }

  public move(distance: number): void {
    let extraDistance = speedBooster.calculateExtraDistance(distance);
    this.position =+ distance + extraDistance;
  }

  // etc...

}
```

I am not too experienced in OOP, and I haven't decided which solution I would go for yet... anyone dares to share their opinions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to overthink it. Both designs are fine for the current level of complexity. I am firmly of the belief that one cannot architect software until one has already made significant headway. At some point in the future, your car may actually need to know if the booster is on, e.g. to repair it or replace it. But for the time being, since all the car cares about is the speed boost, the second solution is slightly cleaner.